# How to create a private conda package for work

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, miniconda

I have created a Python script that holds several functions. I use Conda and I created an environment that has installed all the packages I need in order to run that Python script. Now, my work needs me to share the script with other work colleagues.

Does anyone know how to create a conda package? I cannot find anything relevant with conda (lots with pip!).

Ps. It will be a private package for the company and would be ideal to host it in a private Git repo.

Comment: You probably searched the wrong keyword: for conda you `build` a package. [Here](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda-build/en/latest/user-guide/tutorials/build-pkgs.html) is an example of how that's done. That said, depending on how complex your package is, other solutions may be far simpler than trying to build it as a conda package.